# Cloud9にlaravelをインストールしてphpunitテストするとエラーが出る。

Tags: laravel, phpunit, aws-cloud9

以下、手順を実行したとき、エラーが出てしまいます。

（１）Cloud9にて、laravelをインストール。

（２）route.php を route_a.php にコピー。
route_a.php に以下記述追加

```
Route::get('/test/', function () {
    echo 'test';
});
```

（３）ExampleTest.php を以下のように修正

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->editRoute();

        $this->visit('/')
             ->see('Laravel 5');
        $this->visit('https://laravel-cloned-test1-dog-ears.c9users.io/test/');
    }

    private function editRoute(){
        $this->files = new Filesystem;
        $this->files->move( './app/Http/routes.php', './app/Http/routes_b.php');
        $this->files->move( './app/Http/routes_a.php', './app/Http/routes.php');
        Artisan::call('clear-compiled');
        Artisan::call('cache:clear');        
    }
}
```

（４）phpunitを実行

```
php ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

すると、下記のようなエラーが出ます。

```
There was 1 failure:

1) ExampleTest::testBasicExample
A request to [http://localhost/test] failed. Received status code [404].
```

エラー後、editRoute()をコメントアウトして、
ただテストだけをすると、/test/もテストOKが出ます。

※実際には、editRoute()は外部のクラスに持たせるメソッドですが、
簡略化のため、このような書き方をしています。

どなたか、この問題を解決する方法をご教示願えますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Laravelのテスト機能では、各テストメソッドの前に実行される `TestCase::setUp()` メソッドでLaravelを初期化し、ルーティングなどの設定を読み込んでいます。ですから、テストメソッドで `routes.php` ファイルを変更しても反映されません。Artisanコマンド `clear-compiled` や `cache:clear` もファイルに書き出されたキャッシュを削除するだけですから、同じことです。

このため、テストメソッドごとに routes.php を差し換えたいのであれば、`setUp()` メソッドをオーバーライドして、Laravelが起動する前に行う必要があります。

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->editRoute();

        //あとは通常通りにLaravelを起動させる
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->visit('/test/');
    }

    private function editRoute(){
        // setUp() の時点ではまだLaravelを読み込んでいないので、
        // PHPの標準関数で処理を行う。

        rename('./app/Http/routes.php', './app/Http/routes_b.php');
        rename('./app/Http/routes_a.php', './app/Http/routes.php');

        // もしartisanを呼び出す必要があればexecを使うとか・・・？
    }
}
```

上のコードでは質問に書かれていたものをそのまま再現しましたが、`setUp()` は各テストの前に毎回実行されることに注意してください。もしテストケース（クラス）内で一度だけ書き換えればいいというのであれば、 `setUpBeforeClass()` を使う手もあります。

参考 [PHPUnit マニュアル – 第4章 フィクスチャ](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/ja/fixtures.html)

一応、Laravel起動後でも以下のようにすれば routes.php を再読み込みできるようですが、他に問題が起きないという自信はないです。`setUp()` 内で行ったほうがよいでしょう。

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
    // 既存のルートを全て削除する
    Route::setRoutes(new \Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection);
    // 新しいルートを読み込みなおす
    include(app_path('/Http/routes_a.php'));

    $this->visit('/test');
}
```

なお `visit()` は内部的なルーティングしか行わないので、URLのホスト名は無視されます。実際エラーメッセージでも `localhost` に置き換えられていますね。

> エラー後、editRoute()をコメントアウトして、 ただテストだけをすると、/test/もテストOKが出ます。

質問に書かれたテストを一度実行すると routes.php が書き換えられますから、二回目は上手くいくのだと思います。routes.php を元に戻してからテストすれば、一回目同様エラーになるはずです。